# MLE of variance

Tags: statistics

$f(x) = \theta x^{-(1+\theta)}$ for $x>1$. What is the MLE of the population variance.

I am not sure how I'm supposed to approach this problem. What would be a first step for this?

Comment: Find MLE of $\theta$ and then apply its 'invariance property'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the log likelihood function

$$\ell(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(\theta) - (1+\theta)\ln(x_i).$$
Then, computing the partial derivative,
$$\frac{\partial\ell(\theta)}{\partial \theta}= \frac{n}{\theta} - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)=0.$$
Thus,
$$\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\ln(x_i)},$$
which is, of course, one over the sample mean of the log sample.

Just compute the variance of the random variable with your given pdf $f(x)$ (compute the integrals $E[X]=\int_1^\infty xf(x)dx$ and $E[X^2]=\int_1^\infty x^2f(x)dx$) and then use the above estimator.

Comment: I am only given $\theta >0$ but $E(X^2)$ is only defined for $\theta >2$. What happens when VarX is infinite?

Comment: @Justiceq123 Suppose you find $\hat{\theta}\leq2$ based on your sample, then $\hat{Var[X]}=\infty$. So your variance estimate is simply infinite.

Comment: @Justiceq123 That is precisely a statistical question. You do not know $\theta$. If $\hat{\theta}>2$, then you *can* calculate the MLE of the variance. But, is that correct? Well, you can run a hypothesis test $H:\theta>2$. If the p-value is very small then you reject $H$ and don't calculate the estimation of the variance. If it is large, you do not reject $H$ and consider $\theta>2$ to be reasonable theory, and calculate the estimation of the variance.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it